# C# OnMessage получение ответа

Tags: c#, wpf

Проблема с отображение ответа.

```
var ws = new WebSocket();
ws.Connect();
ws.Send("getonline");
ws.OnMessage += (sender, e) =>
{
    list.Add(e.Data);
    Onlinelbl.Content = list[0].ToString();
};
```

Если писать `MessageBox.Show(list[0].ToString());` то всё хорошо, а если пытаться присвоить текст lbl, то не получается.

Ничего не происходит, `Label` не меняет текст.

Comment: `то не получается` как вы это поняли? Ошибка какая-то или что? Что за проект, winforms?

Comment: проект WPF, ничего не происходит, lbl не меняет текст.

Comment: У вас в стороннем потоке скорее всего возникает исключение, вы можете его увидеть в окне Output в Visual Studio во время отладочного выполнения приложения. Но еще лучше использовать `try-catch` и обрабатывать вероятные исключения нормально.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, список `List<T>` не является потокобезопасным.

Во-вторых вы не можете работать с контролами из стороннего потока.

Решить можно как-то так:

```cs
IProgress<string> progress = new Progress<string>(s => 
{
    list.Add(s);
    Onlinelbl.Content = s;
});

var ws = new WebSocket();
ws.Connect();
ws.Send("getonline");
ws.OnMessage += (sender, e) =>
{
    progress.Report(e.Data);
};
```

`Progress` выполняет свой делегат всегда в том контексте синхронизации, в котором был создан.

*При создании вопросов всегда указывайте, что за сторонние библиотеки вы используете. Мой телепатический навык подсказал, что это `WebSocketSharp`, но не всегда телепатия хорошо работает.*